# How can I derive a GLS estimator for a VECM model

Tags: self-study, generalized-least-squares, vector-error-correction-model

I am still struggling with VECM and VAR models and wish to know how I can derive a  GLS estimator for the following VECM model. How does each step look like? Fi´´How can I derive this estimator for beta conditional on alpha?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest GLS estimation of β given α as in the cointegrated VAR(1) Model. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: The cointegrating vector is typically estimated in a preceding step (e.g. via a Johansen procedure), so that when estimating a VECM $\beta$ is taken as given.

Comment: Ok, I dont think I understand. The estimator would be an expression of alpha and sigma...I guess. But no idea how to do it.

Comment: So far I have to idea how to approach this....

Comment: Feasible GLS estimation of a multivariate model is standard textbook material. Feasible GLS proceeds in two steps: (1) Estimate the system of equations by OLS, obtain the error covariance matrix $\hat\Sigma$. (2) Use the inverse of the error covariance matrix, $\hat\Sigma^{-1}$, as the weighting matrix in GLS estimation. The first step can be substituted by some other way of obtaining $\hat\Sigma$, but the way I indicate above is the simplest one.

Comment: Yeah, I found that but can I apply it to the VECM as well? If yes, is there anything I need to consider?

Comment: Why did you go for the FGLS?

Comment: Actually, that is a good question. Your model seems to have the same right-hand-side variables in all equations, so system-wide GLS collapses to equation-by-equation OLS. I overlooked this at first as I went with your idea to apply GLS.

Comment: Ok, not even more confused. What would you exactly do?

Comment: I would obtain $\beta$ form the Johansen procedure and then estimate the model by equation-by-equation OLS.

Comment: See Section 7.2.2 of Lütkepohl (2005), New Intro to Multiple Time Series Analysis